# Asterisk AGI with chan_lcr

Tags: asterisk, voip, agi

Is there any working example of Asterisk AGI with chan_lcr?

when i call through chan_lcr in AGI it does not work but when i call directly chan_lcr from asterisk dial plan it works.

it seems lcr driver and chan_lcr communicates during call negotiation but Call throgh Asterisk AGI and chan_lcr does not works.

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved that type of problem by commenting AGI command "ChanIsAvail"